# How to convert a []float64 to []byte?

Tags: go

I can't seem to find any clear explanation of how to achieve this. I think my knowledge on type casting and conversion in Go isn't great.

Lets say I have the following slice:

```
myVector := []float64{0.1, 0.4444, 0.9999, 01}
```

For my particular use case I need to convert it into its `[]byte` representation but can't seem to figure it out.

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks.

Comment: what do you expect the `[]byte` representation of that to look like? `[]byte{0, 0, 0, 1}`?

Comment: If you want to encode the float's bits to a []byte instead of the numerical values, then call [math.Float64bits](https://godoc.org/math#Float64bits) to get the float bits. From there, you need to decide how those bytes are encoded to the slice (big endian, little endian).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you always have to iterate over a `slice` to convert it to another type of `slice`:

```golang
myVector := []float64{0.1, 0.4444, 0.9999, 01}

var newSlice []byte
for _, val := range myVektor {
    newVal := convert(val)
    newSlice = append(newSlice, newVal)
}
```

The convert function is up to you depending on what you expect a `float64` to `byte` conversion to look like.

Note: In case `newVal` is not a single value, but multiple use `newSlice = append(newSlice, newVal...)` instead.

Comment: Ah okay. That makes sense. Thank you.